# Typescript: Discriminated Union with value in function parameter resolves to 'any'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Both of these examples fail to see the type of the parameter in `onSelect`... TS claims `value` is `any` if `clearable` is not provided.

I'm at a loss.  I've attempted both with and without a generic: no dice.  Any help?

- [Without Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=71#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0lEkBHAV2CIBMAFHGADOcAN5U4UuADcUAG05IAXHGEwodAOYVK0uGnmooKAEZGA-KubzhSXfoi0AykiMZVACjmKVajdoAlHAAvAB8shDAvLoAvlQ09IzMaKwAwkYoJuZIghAi4pLSPkqq6pq0WnAAPnC0nPLyDtKGxmaWqhpKzVJOru4wXiV+5do1dQ3yweGR0XEJlGhO6nD9SB5s6DAAdABiaQA8GW05eQW1yFw8SAJCwhEhcJ5isgpKADQGmdlGn31u63gsWmEQkemkRBgnCgtDgB14wBkcAA9GF5tRFst4Mcsu1WI8DmsMK9fCEAERmNBkuD-AYhMTeN5IEHiOCxWJfE5GeldJAc1G6Ja0FYAUQAHmB5MA0MAYAA5CAwHE-fFwonwYbkynU2mA+mM3wsl7szm4nL0mx2flohbI5FwADqAAsAJ5wXgQJDCWj4eAAFWccAA1rQIAB3OAAA2GkbgwFEKCjo0qkc+pk48BMMCdjDg2boQdE+dEmE4tAwwCccCdKFEobzLrASAsVCFKwVSu+eNCaoBxM1FNMVJpLj7MH1wyNbOtpCAA) playground
- [With Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=71#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0k4AFHMAZwB4AVAHxwA3lTji4aADaooKAEYyA-AC448iBBkpaFShLgRaAZSQyMagBQA3FFICuSNXwCUcALxDrEYABM9BrYOTnB8egC+VDT0jMxorMgAjvbARL4cENxwSAAeDLS+XOycvFwwUHQA5kKi+hLSsgrKasxSXEgRUZQwAJ5grADC2nKKSHx9rO5wZRW0lXAAPnC09lJSenQMTCxwQ42jGVm5+YXFmbx7KCMy4-01YvXDTSHljp3UlGhGZXCm5jBqZDoGAAOgAYgMeJdrkhDkUlkkUmk4UIppZhHAgo4ADSSJ6jXFGP5IDBwcJuTwiB7iIgwexQWhwHi+YDWOAAegE7yoX1oP2hzw8TOJpKxSHcACIFGgJYYTGYSTB3MIbHZHBSamTwnj9jJla8kNrOXpeT8AKI5MBSYBoYAwAByEBgAtGQp4IvgYsl0tlRIVGGVquCGpEWp1V2eyta7SNXK67PZcAA6gALHpwXwQJBcWj4eB8YxwADWtAgAHc4AADMWVuDAIooKszKqV3HyezwOQwFOMODduhFor9oqYey0DDAIxwFMoIqlvsTJQ877wR3O-EyN0ezFq8VS+QyuUewNikMY8Kx0hAA) playground

```
import React from 'react';

interface RequiredProps {
    value: string;
    clearable?: false;
    onSelect: (value: string) => void;
}

interface ClearableProps {
    value: string | null;
    clearable?: true;
    onSelect: (value: string | null) => void;
}

const Select: React.FC<ClearableProps | RequiredProps> = ({ value, clearable, onSelect }) => {
    return <div />;
}

const Clearable = <Select value="abc" onSelect={(value) => { }} clearable={true} />;
const ExplicitNotClearable = <Select value="abc" onSelect={(value) => { }} clearable={false} />;

// Why doesn't TS know `value` is a `string`, but rather thinks this function has no type?
const NotClearable = <Select value="abc" onSelect={(value) => { }} />;
```

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props<T> {
    clearable?: boolean;
    onSelect: (value: T) => void;
    value: T;
}

interface RequiredProps extends Props<string> {
    clearable?: false;
}

type ClearableType = string | null;
interface ClearableProps extends Props<ClearableType> {
    clearable: true;
}

const Select: React.FC<ClearableProps | RequiredProps> = ({ value, clearable, onSelect }) => {
    return <div />;
}

const Clearable = <Select value="abc" onSelect={(value) => { }} clearable={true} />;
const ExplicitNotClearable = <Select value="abc" onSelect={(value) => { }} clearable={false} />;

// Why doesn't TS know `value` is a `string`, but rather thinks this function has no type?
const NotClearable = <Select value="abc" onSelect={(value) => { }} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused because in your two cases, `clearable` is either optional or required in `ClearableProps`.  I expect you mean it to be required in both versions, right?  Anyway, I will assume that.

This looks like a known bug, [microsoft/TypeScript#31618](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31618).  The `value` callback parameter is not being [contextually typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) when the callback is assigned to a union-typed `onSelect` property.  When you explicitly discriminate the union by setting `clearable` the problem goes away.

This issue is on the backlog, so it's not likely to be addressed anytime soon.

You can work around this by explicity *annotating* the type of `value`:

```
const ImplicitlyNotClearable = <Select value="abc" onSelect={(value: string) => { }} />;
```

which isn't the best, but it least it's something.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCuADsYkpN0lEkBHAV2CIBMAFHGADOcAN5U4UuADcUAG05IAXHGEwodAOYVK0uGnmooKAEZGA-KubzhSXfoi0AykiMZVACjmKVajdoAlHAAvAB8shDAvLoAvlQ09IzMaKwAwkYoJuZIghAi4pLSPkqq6pq0WnAAPnC0nPLyDtKGxmZGqhpKzVJOru4wXiV+5do1dQ3yweGR0XEJlGhO6nD9SB5s6DAAdABiaQA8GW05eQW1yFw8SAJCwhEhcJ5isgpKADQGmdlGn31u63gsWmEQkemkRBgnCgtDgB14wBkcAA9GF5tRFst4Mcsu1WI8DmsMK9fCEAERmNBkuD-AYhMTeN5IEHiOCxWJfE5GeldJAc1G6Ja0FYAUQAHmB5MA0MAYAA5CAwHE-fFwonwYbkynU2mA+mM3wsl7szm4nL0mx2flohZClYASXAUplMHkAE8FUrvnjQmqAcTNRTTFSaS5-TB9cMygFKka2dbdJIgA)